# Почему послдений элемент не оборачивается в td?

Tags: javascript, for

```js
let table = document.createElement('table');
    
    document.body.prepend(table); 
    
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        table.prepend(row);
        row.innerHTML = 'Hello';
    
        for(let c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            let col = document.createElement('td');
            row.prepend(col);
            col.innerHTML = 'Hello';
        }
    }
```

```css
table tr td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё правильно оборачивается, просто вы зачем-то пишете строчку Hello внутрь tr, вот она и отображается "необернутая"

```js
let table = document.createElement('table');
    
    document.body.prepend(table); 
    
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        table.prepend(row);
        // убрать эту строчку
        // row.innerHTML = 'Hello';
    
        for(let c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            let col = document.createElement('td');
            row.prepend(col);
            col.innerHTML = 'Hello'+' ' + i + ' ' + c;
        }
    }
```

```css
table tr td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```